# Pass the outputs of the shared layer to a layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a problem where I have to create a list of same shared layer and pass it to another layer . so I used the for loop and added to a list.  Then I have to pass those out puts to another layer. List can't be passed to another layer. How to execute this ?

```
x = Input(shape=...)
shared_layer = MySharedLayer(...)
outputs=[]
# Step 2: Iterate for Ty steps
for t in range(Ty):
   out = output_layer(x)
   outputs.append(out)
lastlayer=Dense(shape=...)(outputs)
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass a list of outputs from shared_layer to last_layer?

Comment: Shouldn't you **concatenate** the **outputs** and then use  **Dense(number_of_neurons)(concatenated_output)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply use `keras.layers.Concatenate`, concatenate layer concatenates a list of inputs.

```
x = Input(shape=...)
shared_layer = MySharedLayer(...)
outputs=[]
# Step 2: Iterate for Ty steps
for t in range(Ty):
   out = output_layer(x)
   outputs.append(out)
concat = concatenate(outputs)
lastlayer=Dense(shape=...)(concat)
```